# C++ Weird error. Fails to compile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, allegro5

I have been using the allegro 5 libraries for developing a game in C++ for some time. Today I got some weird error:

I have a class called `level`. I have a header file called `levelhandler`.
Here's how it looks:

```
#pragma once
#include "level.h"

level level_1;

level *currentlevel;

void initialize_levels()
{

   currentlevel = &level_1;

}
```

When I try to compile it gives me strange errors like:

```
error C2086: 'int level' redefinition
error C2143: syntax error : missing ; before 'level_1'
```

I remember that it could compile before, and I did use `currentlevel->Player.X` a lot of times, but now I have a lot of that and it gives errors like these:

```
error C2227: left of '->Player' must point to a class/struct/generic type
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed
```

---

*header pasted from comment*

```
#pragma once
#include "entity.h"
// some more includes
class level {
public:
    enum Tileset { ... };
    enum Tile { ... };
    int tiles[200][200];
    player Player;
    level(void);
    ~level(void);
};
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot the ; after the class definition in your header file. I got almost the same errors with a test program where the ; is missing : http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/Jd7

Comment: Maybe the header declares `level` inside a namespace?

Comment: No. A header file is not part of any class. It may define the class though. Would you show the header file `level.h`?

Comment: the class was made using a class wizard and there is a ;. The funny thing is that the compiler acts like it didn't knew level was an object even though when I mouse over it it says class level, and when I type level_1. intellisense lists the members, only the compiler acts this weird, and when i typed in the exact same code into an other project, with the level object and levelhandler it compiles perfectly fine

Comment: @harper the header file looks like this:
'
#pragma once
#include "entity.h"
some more includes

class level
{
public:
enum Tileset { ... };
enum Tile { ... };
int tiles[200][200];
player Player;
level(void);
~level(void);
};
'

Comment: This display code compiles fine here. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: It seems you might have a `#pragma once` in a cpp file. I'm not familiar enough with how that works in VC++ to know if that could cause a problem (probably not), but it's very likely unnecessary. The problem may be in `entity.h`, please post it (as an edit to the question, not in the comments). Better yet, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as [@harper said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16739479/1270168).

Comment: you could try to put your level decl and def in a namespace, it is anyway good code practice to use namespaces to avoid polluting the global namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such errors are hard to find as long as you look at the "Error List" pane. Select View/Output to show the "Output" view. The line after the error C2086 shows the original definition of level.

You fill find an

```
int level;
```

there as the C2086 tells you. If it's the line

```
level level_1;
```

of your fist example you will have to check the last header file include in your compilation unit. It might end with an `int` or it has a unbalanced `#if` clause.

To find the exact location start using a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). This helps you to find the bug and saves time of other with their crystal balls.

*Edit:*

Another way to find the reason for this unexpected behavior is to see the preprocessor output. Set the `Generate Preprocessed File` option int the C/C++/Preprocessor project property page to **`With line numbers (/P)`** and look in the generated `<sourcefile>.i`

Check that that level.h file has included what you intended.

Comment: Ok, so the int level : redefinition actually points to line 6 which is the second level object, I'm guessing it is because it doesn't see level as a type specifier so it takes it as a default int, and that gives a c2146 syntax error "missing ';' before identifier level_1. And when it reads line 6 it gives the redefinition error. The only thing i don't understand is why would that happen if while typing the code, the program clearly recognizes class level and even lists its members. I even copy-pasted the headers and the object into a new project and compiles perfectly fine

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you can click the "Accept" check m ark.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've been tinkering around with my project the weekend, and I finally found out what whas the problem that gave me so many weird compiler errors. It seems that I had a lot of cases where two header files were including each other, and the compiler really didn't like that, so I corrected that, and now I'm ok. Thank you all for helping me, and have a great day!